# Why .profile (and not .bashrc) appends ~/bin to path?

Tags: command-line, bash, .profile

Since `.bashrc` is more "generic" (in the sense that `.profile` sources it), why "include `~/bin` to path" procedure is not inside `.bashrc`? Why the user would not want it in a non-login shell? (Especially nowadays, where non-login shells are more common*.)

I know I can manually do such change, but I want to know if there is a reason.

*can't prove it, but I think that is the case.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

`~/.bashrc` and `/etc/bash.bashrc` are run every time an interactive `bash` shell is started.

In contrast, `~/.profile` and `/etc/profile` are run every time any *login* shell is started. So it does not have to be a `bash` shell, but it does have to be a *login shell* (and many `bash` shell instances are not *login shells*).

- A `bash` shell is a shell where the shell program that provides it is [`bash`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/precise/en/man1/bash.1.html), rather than some other program, such as [`dash`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/precise/en/man1/dash.1.html).
- A login shell is a shell that is started automatically as a consequence of logging in, to provide the user interface (graphical or command-line) for the login. When a login shell is exited, the login terminates.

Therefore, putting a commend that appends entries to `PATH` in a `bashrc` file would:

1. **Do nothing** when the shell is not `bash`, which is often the case. For example, `PATH` would be unmodified when you're in a graphical login session. Remember, `PATH` is not just used by command-line programs.
2. **Append it over and over again** in the presence of nested `bash` shells. So, if you start a shell within a shell--which is very common, for a variety of reasons--then you'll have multiple `~/bin` entries stacked onto your `PATH`. This makes the `PATH` environment variable difficult to read, and sometimes also decreases performance.

These would be undesirable. Thus it would be *wrong* to put this in a `bashrc` file; it really belongs in `~/.profile`. `~/.profile` is *the right place* for:

```
# set PATH so it includes user's private bin if it exists
if [ -d "$HOME/bin" ] ; then
    PATH="$HOME/bin:$PATH"
fi
```

Non-login shells have login shells (or something that behaves like a login shell) as their parent, and inherit most of their environment variables, including `PATH`, from this login shell. So putting path-modifying commands in `~/.profile` requires that you log out and back in for them to be effective, but it affects the environment of non-login shells too (as well as the environment for programs that are not shells, since every program gets its own set of environment variables--called its "environment"--inherited from its parent process).

Comment: I understand. But this decision still doesn't make sense for me. If a open a terminal right now it loads only .bashrc, then I wont able to see my private bin.

Comment: @borges If the default configuration doesn't work well for you, you should feel free to change it. (It's your computer, after all. Or at least your account.) But this sounds like a one-time thing. That is, is sounds like your private `bin` directory didn't exist when you logged on, and that you have created it during this login session. If you log out and back in, it will be in your `PATH`. Since creating your private `bin` directory is something that only needs to be done once, this is a one-time inconvenience.

Answer (score 3):

It's because traditionally environment variables go only in `/etc/profile` or `.profile`. The `bashrc` file is for things like aliases, prompt settings, shell options and so forth (i.e. things that relate directly to the shell).