# Ensuring .profile gets executed when using nX

Tags: environment-variables, nx, .profile

The `$PATH` I have when I run terminal in an nX session is different to that I have when I run terminal after logging on physically.

The former is

```
/home/agrimm/.rbenv/shims:/home/agrimm/.rbenv/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games
```

while the latter is

```
/home/agrimm/.rbenv/bin:/home/agrimm/.rbenv/shims:/home/agrimm/.rbenv/bin:/home/agrimm/bin:/usr/lib/lightdm/lightdm:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games
```

The latter has `/home/agrimm/bin/` while the former doesn't (and yes, I've rebooted since creating `/home/agrimm/bin`)

I suspect the difference is that `.profile` is getting run in the latter, but not in the former.

https://askubuntu.com/a/279374/14772 has in the last paragraph:

> Non-login shells have login shells (or something that behaves like a
>   login shell) as their parent, and inherit most of their environment
>   variables, including `PATH`, from this login shell. So putting
>   path-modifying commands in `~/.profile` requires that you log out and
>   back in for them to be effective, but it affects the environment of
>   non-login shells too (as well as the environment for programs that are
>   not shells, since every program gets its own set of environment
>   variables--called its "environment"--inherited from its parent
>   process).

I assume that logging in with nX is "something that behaves like a login shell", and that when I run terminal, the parent process of terminal ought to provide it with a complete $PATH, including `home/agrimm/bin`.

Is my assumption correct? If so, how do I get nX to run `.profile`?